# Algorithm to update only the changed innerHTML of the document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 JS variables. `before` and `after`. They contains the SAME html document, but have some modification. About 1%-10% change between them. I want to update the body from `before` to `after`. The variables`before` and `after` are raw string.

I can do something like that:

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML=after
```

The problem is that if I render this way it not look good. The render takes time, and there is a white screen between the renders. I want to show the user 10 modification in a second (video of modifications)

So what I want to do. I want to **search and find** only the elements that changed only by analyze the HTML text of `before` and `after`.

**My way of solution:**

I can find the changes and the position in the text using [Javascript Library for diff & match & patch](https://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_diff.html).

**The question is:**

After I find the text changes. How to find only the elements who changed. I update only those elements.

I thought, maybe to create a range, that contains every change, and update the range, but how exactly to do that?

If anything unclear, please comment, I will explain better.

Comment: This is not a good approach.

Comment: What do you mean? this what I need. I have two texts of same document. after some modification. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: One of the things you can do for events is that when you create the document(the after) you add classes for every generated tags. Then after each reassigning document.innerHTML you can set events to different classes

Comment: I prefer to only make changed to the document and not render all. If make a short white screen. It takes some miliseconds.

Comment: nAviD is right.. this approach is horrid. you lose the events/etc cos the events are loaded after the dom, and you don't reload all the events.. im guessing theres huge amounts of duplicate.. you should consider just having your html/js markup + using jquery to manipulate after

Comment: To come up with a definition of "what has been changed?" is not easy even for a human.

Comment: I can find what changed. I can tell you for example the HTML text between `start` of 60 to `80` changed from `<b>hello world</b>` to `<br><b style=color:red>after</b>:' The question is how to apply the changed after that.

Comment: The `events` is not the hard issue. The issue is how to render only what changed

Comment: I give some text you say "what is changed?". Assume that each number is an element.
first group :"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"  and "1 2 3 4 4 4 5 6 7 7 7 8 9 9 "
second :"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9" and "1 [newLine] 2 3 4 5 6 7 [newLine] 8 9"
third:"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9" and "1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 5"..

for each group of before and after please as a human! tell me what changed(what is added, what is removed and what is altered ? 
.

Comment: if you can say a definition for "CHANGE" then maybe one can solve this.

Comment: Did you ever used DIFF command. Or used git? both telling you what changed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a very good library for it: https://github.com/patrick-steele-idem/morphdom

> Lightweight module for morphing an existing DOM node tree to match a
>   target DOM node tree. It's fast and works with the real DOM—no virtual
>   DOM here!

Very easy to use, and doing exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, then what I would have done is,
1) Make a new object (view Object) which will control the rendering of DOM elements. (Similar to MVC)
2) In this object, I would have created 3 functions.

```
a) init function  (contains the event-handlers)
b) render1 function (which will contain elements in before element)  
c) render2 function (which will contain elements in after element)
```

Whenever there is an event where I need to change the HTML of a class/id/body/document, I will change that in init function and call render2 function which contains the after element.
This should not give any error, however the browser has to work to render all the page, but rendering can be divided over multiple elements of document. So, whenever you need to **render a part of document, make  separate render functions.**

p.s. there can be different approaches.

Comment: Thank. But The big question is, how do I find which elements to render.

Comment: So, you are talking about text and I responded in terms of blocks on a document.

Comment: Exactly I have raw string

Comment: But isn't it the bad approach? I mean, comparing text (algorithm) will take more time than rendering the document.

Comment: But it's working behind the scene. The rendering it visually takes time. I can compare and make list of changes before starting the video

Answer (score 0):

You must implement the [LCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)(Longest Common Subsequence). To understand better of this algorithm you can watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnD96abizww) youtube video. Also It's easier to first study [Longest Common Substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem).

Comment: The alogirthm you mention can tell me what changed. But I'm searching to the HTML DOM element that  changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution. `virtual-dom` can do the work for me. I can create two VTree, make a diff, and apply a patch.

**From the documentation of `virtual-dom`:**

`virtual-dom` is what I need.

> Manual DOM manipulation is messy and keeping track of the previous DOM
>   state is hard. A solution to this problem is to write your code as if
>   you were recreating the entire DOM whenever state changes. Of course,
>   if you actually recreated the entire DOM every time your application
>   state changed, your app would be very slow and your input fields would
>   lose focus.
>
> virtual-dom is a collection of modules designed to provide a
>   declarative way of representing the DOM for your app. So instead of
>   updating the DOM when your application state changes, you simply
>   create a virtual tree or VTree, which looks like the DOM state that
>   you want. virtual-dom will then figure out how to make the DOM look
>   like this efficiently without recreating all of the DOM nodes.
>
> virtual-dom allows you to update a view whenever state changes by
>   creating a full VTree of the view and then patching the DOM
>   efficiently to look exactly as you described it. This results in
>   keeping manual DOM manipulation and previous state tracking out of
>   your application code, promoting clean and maintainable rendering
>   logic for web applications.

https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom